# VBA refuses to launch

Tags: excel, vba

I have several Excel 2007 VBA solutions which have been running fine for years. In mid-December 2018 I got a new computer and installed Office 2007 and all was fine until about three days ago, when as soon as I tried to run a solution or enter the VBA or macro section under the developer tab, I get a message "Unable to load VBE6EXT.OLB", and then a message saying "Out of memory", but the Excel (non-VBA) part continues to function. I have tried every "solution" I found on the web, including uninstalling and reinstalling Office, checking the register for entries said be necessary (they were there - no problem), copying said file from its location in Program Files (x86) to same location in Program Files, checking that Office executables are all running under Windows 7 compatibility, and maybe more that I can't remember. Has anyone encountered this issue? I can't think of anything else to try!

Comment: Don't anthropomorphize VBA.

Comment: Office 2007 exceeded extended support in 2017 already. Update to a more recent version.

Comment: On your old machine did you have an older version of Office installed? say 2003?

Comment: IAmNerd2000: No - the old machine was not that old!

Comment: Peh - I know. I am checking out 2019 for compatibility with my solutions.

Comment: rory ap - attribute human characteristics or behavior to (a god, animal, or object).
"people's tendency to anthropomorphize their dogs" ???

Comment: @JohnL So make it compatible to the new version then. Put your effort in updating your code to the new version instead of trying to fix a dying software. You will run into issues with your old Excel soon or later anyway. Then you have wasted your time.

Comment: Peh (2) That's my plan.